# Is there a way to search a String of lyrics then substring out the matching phrases

Tags: java, string, search, substring, indexof

I need to search lyrics for a matching phrase.

For example:

I have song lyrics like these.

"**She** is the one that I **love**, I know it something something something something something **she loves** you and **me** something something something."

---

Given this search term below, search the lyrics for the closest match and count the characters in the sub string. My issue is finding the closest match using `indexOf` returns the first SHE. I need the to be able to sub string out the closes matching phrase.

**The results should print** :

The closest matching search for 'she loves me' is "she loves you and me".

Index Length: 20

Answer (score 1):

I know its not the most optimized or the efficient one. But, the following code will work for most keywords.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class KeywordSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getMatchingLyrics("She is the one that I love, "
                + "I know it something something something something something "
                + "she loves you and me something something something.", 
                Arrays.asList("she you".toLowerCase().split(" "))));
    }

    private static String getMatchingLyrics(String lyrics, List<String> keywords) {
        String[] lyricWords = lyrics.split(" ");

        // Split and get the word index for keyword matches
        Map<Integer, String> lyricEngine = new TreeMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < lyricWords.length; i++) {
            String search = lyricWords[i].toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
            if (keywords.contains(search) && !lyricEngine.values().contains(lyricWords[i])) {
                lyricEngine.put(i, lyricWords[i]);
            }
        }

        Integer min = null;
        Integer max = null;
        if (lyricEngine.size() == 1) {
            return lyricEngine.values().iterator().next();
        } else if (lyricEngine.size() <= keywords.size()) {
            List<Integer> coll = new ArrayList<>(lyricEngine.keySet());
            min = coll.get(0);
            max = coll.get(lyricEngine.size() - 1);
        } else {
            // Prepare the difference between the indexes
            Map<Integer, String> set = new TreeMap<>(); 
            List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>(lyricEngine.keySet());
            for(int i=0; i <= lyricEngine.size() - keywords.size(); i++) {
                int j = i + keywords.size() - 1;
                int diff = keys.get(j);
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(keys.get(j) + "");
                for (j = j - 1; j >= i; j--) {
                    diff -= keys.get(j);
                    str.append(',');
                    str.append(keys.get(j));
                }
                set.put(diff, str.toString());
            }

            // Get the value with minimum difference
            for(String s:set.get(set.keySet().toArray()[0]).split(",")) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(s);
                if (min == null && max == null) {
                    max = x;
                    min = x;
                } else {
                    if (x > max) {
                        max = x;
                    } else if (x < min) {
                        min = x;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Build the string from indexes
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
            s.append(lyricWords[i]);
            if (i < max) {
                s.append(" ");
            }
        }
        return s.toString();
    }
}
```

You can build and optimize it as per your need. Explanations are given as comments. If you have any doubt, feel free to ask me in DM or comments.

For different keywords,

```
Keyword: she loves me
Output: she loves you and me

Keyword: I love it
Output: I love, I know it

Keyword: she is one love
Output: She is the one that I love,
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this should get me in the correct direction of what I need to do !!

Comment: I added a set of testing lyrics that I need to parse and I come up with an array out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: Check where it is throwing exception(line number) and debug the code and check the actual value before exception. And add any conditions if required like `array.length > 0`

Comment: Probably none of the keywords might have matched the lyrics. causing `for(String s:set.get(set.keySet().toArray()[0]).split(",")) {` this line to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: This line here breaks it          for(int i=0; i <= lyricEngine.size() - keywords.size(); i++) {.....If the lyrics engine.size is only 2 then it only found 2 of the 3 search words so it won't go inside that loop to fill the set.

Comment: This is the case that for this song, the only key words found were {43=she, 92=you}. Int i =0, and when we compute lyrics.size-keyword size it is 2-3=-1  in this case because less words were found then what was searched.

Comment: @JohnHanewich I've updated the answer with few more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own sophisticated algorithm in Java because in JDK we don't have an appropriate solution out of the box. But in Java world are a lot of suitable solution you could try to solve your issue by using Apache Lucene.